# Python defining multimodal function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need no create a function that can tell if:

- There´s no mode
- There´s 1 mode
- And if is multimodal list

I got the first 2 points cover:

```
lista = [1,2,2,3,3,4]
contador = {}

for i in lista:
    cuenta = lista.count(i)
    contador[i] = cuenta

maximo =(0)
moda = [0]

for i in contador:
    if(contador[i]>maximo):
        maximo = contador[i]
        moda = i
        freq = contador[i]


if maximo == 1:
    print("There is no mode")
else:
    print ("Mode is: %d, with a frequency of: %d" % (moda, freq))
```

But I´m struggling to find a way to define if a list is multimodal. I thought of first defining which frequency is the highest and then check `contador` to take out all frequencies below but it doesn´t seem to work:

```
for i in contador:
    if contador[i] < max:
        delete = [i]
        del contador[delete]
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def moda(x):
    input_string = input("Lista de numeros separados por un espacio: ")
    lista = input_string.split()
    contador = {}
    for i in lista:
        cuenta = lista.count(i)
        contador[i] = cuenta
    maximo =(0)
    for i in contador:
        if(contador[i]>maximo):
            maximo = contador[i]
        modas = {}
        for i in contador:
            if contador[i] == maximo:
                modas[i] = contador[i]
    if maximo == 1:
        return("No hay modas")
    elif len(modas)>1:
        return ("Las modas y sus frecuencias son:")
        return (modas)
    else:
        return ("la moda y su frecuencia es:")
        return (modas)
```

Answer (score 1):

well for multimodial you need to check the max frequency and count the frequency count. if it is 1 then mean no mode, more then 1 and exactly 1 then there is 1 mode and i frequency count is more than 1 and has multiple value has same count then it is multimodial

```
lista = [1,2,3,3,4]

res  = {}
for i in lista:
    if i not in res.keys():
        res[i]=1
    else:
        res[i]+=1
freq = res.values()
max_freq = max(freq)
if max_freq==1:
    print('no mode')
else:
    key = ''
    if list(freq).count(max_freq)==1:
        for k, v in res.items():
            if v==max_freq:
                print('mode is {}, frequency is {}'.format(k, max_freq))
                break
    else:
        print('multimodeal')
        for k, v in res.items():
            if v==max_freq:
                print('mode is {}, frequency is {}'.format(k, max_freq))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest modification to your existing code would be something like:

```
maximo = 0
moda = []

for i in contador:
    if(contador[i] > maximo):
        maximo = i
        freq = contador[i]
        moda = []
    if(contador[i]==freq):
        moda.append(i)
```

And change the final `print` to:

```
print ("Mode is: %s, with a frequency of: %d" % (moda, freq))
```

The whole thing simplified with library functions:

```
from collections import Counter

lista = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]

contador = Counter(lista)
# get the second part (the count) from the first element of the first most common element
freq = contador.most_common(1)[0][1]
# get all the x's for which the count is freq
moda = [x for x, c in contador.items() if c == freq]

if freq == 1:
    print("There is no mode")
else:
    print("Mode is: %s, with a frequency of: %d" % (moda, freq))
```